# Why is Fetch API call not returning the response headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I'm building a SignUp form and have the following API call to POST the form:

```
const request = new Request('http://localhost:4300/auth/', {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: new Headers({
   'Accept'       : 'application/json',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
 }),
 body: JSON.stringify({ user: data })
});

fetch(request).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const auth = response.headers.get('Authorization');
    console.log(auth)
});
```

The problem is `response.headers.get('Authorization')` is returning as `null`. Even though if I look at Chrome's Network XHR request I see the Response Headers being sent by the API server.

Why is React not providing me with `response.headers` via the request above?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of the [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) for the response from `http://localhost:4300/auth/` must include "`Authorization`" if you want your requesting frontend JavaScript code to be allowed to access the `Authorization` response header value.

If the response includes no value for the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header, the only response headers browsers will let you access from client-side JavaScript in your web app are `Cache-Control`,
`Content-Language`,
`Content-Type`,
`Expires`,
`Last-Modified`
and
`Pragma`.

See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name for the spec.

Comment: Thanks but not following... Are you saying I need to update the server or the client? I'm fairly certain it's the client that's the issue because the API endpoint is working with a different client library in the same way. I'm just trying to build the SignUp flow outside of the orig client library.

Comment: For example, the client library works just fine, here's the source: https://github.com/timscott/react-devise/blob/master/src/actions/api.js

Comment: Notice how tryLogin is able to get the response.headers --- https://github.com/timscott/react-devise/blob/master/src/actions/actions.js

Comment: I'm trying to build my own SignUp form outside of that library and while the API is responding the same, my client code isn't getting response.headers ... any ideas? Thanks

Comment: you must update your api endpoint or serve your client files from same port

Comment: You need to update the server. There is no change you can make on the client side only that will allow your frontend JavaScript code to get access to the Authorization header if the server does not explicitly allow it. The browser is the client blocking your frontend JavaScript code from accessing that header. That’s why you can see it in your browser devtools but not from your frontend code. That’s the way the CORS protocol works: The browser is the sole enforcement point—the sole point where anything gets blocked—but the browser behaves according to response headers sent by servers.

Comment: I appreciate the reply but that doesn't add up.. The server is already working fine via another form in my client. I'm just trying to build a new client so it can't be a server issue.

Comment: I'm also using devise-jwt which is what is sending back the headers

Comment: As far as I can see https://github.com/timscott/react-devise is something you need to install in the (node?) environment on the server that serves your frontend code? At least I see `yarn add react-devise` in the readme, and I see code examples there which are clearly not JavaScript code for running in a browser on the client side. So I guess the reason that works is that it must be causing the request to be made from server side rather than being made directly from your frontend JavaScript code using XHR or the Fetch API underneath.

Comment: The bottom line, I assure you it adds up and that what I’ve explained in the answer is the cause of the problem described in the question, and there’s no way you’re going to be able to make the request using the Fetch API in your frontend code and get to the value of the Authorization unless the server response includes Authorization in the  Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header